# A non-polynomial function whose first $n$ derivatives are positive but all $m > n$ derivatives take both negative and positive values

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Does there exist non-polynomial $C^{\infty}$ function $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$  whose first $n$ derivatives are positive but whose derivatives of order $m > n$ take on both negative and positive values. Is there a simple example?

I'm not sure about how I would go about constructing such a function but help would be appreciated. I've attempted considering a chain-rule approach, but I've had no luck so far.

Comment: $f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+\ldots+a_n x^n+a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+\ldots+a_{n+m}x^{n+m},\,a_i>0,i=1,\ldots,n$

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that the function is non-polynomial. One approach I've considered is taking some non-polynomial function, say $\tanh$ and then composing it into your $f(x)$ but that doesn't get us over the finish line. @Artem

Comment: Do you mean a special point or the whole domain of the function?

Comment: The whole domain or some compact interval, say [-1,1].

Comment: Let's focus on the interval for now... I was hoping some sort of $f(\tanh(x))$ might work.. When we derive this we start getting some $a'b + b'a$ interactions that make this quite difficult.

Comment: It is not reasonable to forbid polynomials. For the whole real domain they do not help and for the interval a sum of polynomial and non-polynomial function will work.

Comment: I'm fine to use the sum of a polynomial and a non-pomynomial. Those functions are non-polynomial.

Comment: $(x+3)^n+\sin x $. Should I post this as answer?

Comment: Would $(x+3)^n + \tanh(x)$ work as well? For which intervals is this valid?

Comment: Your question is about the interval $[-1,1] $, but the generalization of my answer on any interval which is bounded from below is obvious.

Comment: Construct a polynomial $P(x)$ that satisfies your conditions.  Let $f(x)=AP(x)+ae^x$, with very large $A$ and very small $a$.

Comment: Either of you feel free to provide an answer :)

Comment: @herb the mth derivative of ae^x is doesn't take both negative and positive values...

Comment: $MadcowD  The point is that $P(x)$ does satisfy the desired conditions and adding a very small non-polynomial won't affect the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any interval $[a,b] $ with $-\infty<a <b\le+\infty $ the function
$$(x-a+2)^n+\sin x
$$
will satisfy the requirements.